# pro ASP.NET MVC SportsStore chapter 7-9 Error Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I am trying to run SportsStore from book pro ASP.NET MVC 3 .
I do every step i installed Ninject but i get an error in the last line of following code which says     ..
    'ninjectControllerFactory' could not be found (a re you missing using directive or an assebly reference )

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to run downloaded proper version yet it says sport store domain is unavailable due to wrong version of Visual Studio.

I tried both express 2010 and 2012 (MVC 3)

Any ideas?

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        // Use LocalDB for Entity Framework by default
        Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlConnectionFactory(@"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True");

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Ninject ASP.NET MVC3 package doesn't use a controller factory, but makes use of the IDependencyResolver interface. So either you have to implement your own ControllerFactory or even better use Ninject.Web.MVC3 as described in the wiki:

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/MVC3

Comment: HM i followed exact steps in the book. So i think i have ControllerFactory in class NinjectControllerFactory.

Comment: debbuging does not open a browser it just states the above mentioned error but BOOK says: If you select Start Debugging from the Debug menu, you’ll see an error page. This is because you’ve
requested a URL that’s associated with a controller that Ninject doesn’t have a binding for, as shown in
Figure 7-4.

Comment: Sry I don't know that book. I'm just telling you how it should be done correctly. The book obviously uses an outdated way to get Ninject running in MVC3.

Comment: Right i should work something out by using tutorial. Great thanks any way

Comment: CTRL + . (dot)  on a uderlined text will let to add using statment that was needed. Uff so much time wasted :)

Comment: If anyone would find problems with a book here is a link to a forum topic covering it: http://forums.asp.net/t/1781349.aspx/1